# Change the style of a date picker

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, uidatepicker, uiappearance

I was wondering how I can change the style of a montouch datepicker? I've managed to customise the borders around the picker itself, but I'm not sure how to customise the picker.

Any help is appreciated.

Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most native iOS controls, Apple is very restrictive about customization and will not allow you to modify many of their properties.  Apple did this deliberately to give a consistent look-and-feel to all apps, among other reasons.

To wit, observe how few properties there are for UIKit.UIDatePicker: http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UIDatePicker%2fP

If you want a highly-customized date picker, you will need to roll your own.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. I was just checking to see if there was any quick way to change some of the colours etc. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

The [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIDatePicker.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIDatePicker-SW3) says it all:

> Appearance of Date Pickers:
>
> You cannot customize the appearance of date pickers.

Answer (score 0):

To change the color use the following in viewDidLoad() as one example:

```
 yourPicker.setValue(UIColor.blueColor(), for Key: "textColor")
```

On a side note it still amazes me that the default blue color isn't the same light blue that's pretty standard on apple devices.